# Symfony http: TLS handshake error from [::1]

Tags: php, symfony, localhost

Using `symfony 3.4` and `PHP 7.1`, while running the project it forcing to run at `https` localhost, but not displaying content with https. and how can I run with normal `http`.

not running at `https` as well. after install local `ca`

```
symfony server:ca:install
```

not running after enabling `http`.

```
symfony local:server:start --allow-http
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

type symfony server:ca:uninstall to get ride of your tls errors. That's how I solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

a - you should first stop running the server
b - run the command above
c - and then restart the server

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To make your post more accessible, you should avoid using screenshots and maybe recheck the markdown-guide. I think, you forgot to make the trailing spaces to do the line break in your list,

Answer (score 0):

for me i only , instead of
"symfony serve"
i run
"symfony serve -no-tls"
Then i have no error and i could view the result on "http://127.0.0.1:8000" instead of "https://127.0.0.1:8000"